# Electromagnetic field invariants with imaginary time relativity

Tags: electromagnetism, general-relativity, vacuum

On this formulation of relativity, a coordinate in space-time is identified with

$$\chi = \left(x,y,z,ict\right)$$

Where we are considering flat space-time, so there is no distinction made between covariant and contravariant indices.

From here, the electromagnetic tensor is found to be

$$\mathbb{F} = \begin{bmatrix}
 0 & B_{3} & -B_{2} & -\frac{i}{c}E_{1} \\
 -B_{3} & 0 & B_{1} & -\frac{i}{c}E_{2} \\
 B_{2} & -B_{1} & 0 & -\frac{i}{c}E_{3} \\
 \frac{i}{c}E_{1} & \frac{i}{c}E_{2} & \frac{i}{c}E_{3} & 0 \\
 \end{bmatrix}$$

I'm trying to calculate the invariant $F_{\mu \nu}F_{\mu \nu}$ which is supposed to be $c^2B^2-E^2$. Here are my calculations

$$ F_{\mu \nu}F_{\mu \nu} = F_{1 \nu}F_{1 \nu} + F_{2 \nu}F_{2 \nu} + F_{3 \nu}F_{3 \nu} + F_{4 \nu}F_{4 \nu}$$

$$ = F_{12}F_{12} + F_{13}F_{13} + F_{14}F_{14} $$
$$ + F_{21}F_{21} + F_{23}F_{23} + F_{24}F_{24} $$
$$ + F_{31}F_{31} + F_{32}F_{32} + F_{34}F_{34} $$
$$ + F_{41}F_{41} + F_{42}F_{42} + F_{43}F_{43} $$
$$=  2 \left( F_{12}^2 + F_{13}^2 + F_{14}^2 + F_{23}^2 + F_{24}^2 + F_{34}^2 \right)$$
$$= 2 \left( B_{3}^2 + B_{2}^2 - \frac{1}{c^2} E_{1}^2 + B_{1}^2 - \frac{1}{c^2}E_{2}^2 - \frac{1}{c^2}E_{3}^2 \right)$$
$$= \frac{2}{c^2} \left(C^2B^2 - E^2\right)$$

which has an additional factor of $2C^2$ compared to the answer I expected. I know that, using the usual notation for relativity, with the metric $+++-$, this invariant is written as $F_{\mu \nu} F^{\mu \nu}$, and that $F^{\mu \nu} \propto \frac{1}{2} F_{\mu \nu}$, but here, as one is not making the distinction between covariant and contravariant indices, this makes no sense. Does the value of the invariant changes in this formulation, or where am I wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to answer an exercise or are you doing this calculation for yourself?

I mean just at the first look, it seems that you are missing also a minus sign. The step from the third last line to the second last line seems wrong. All quantities in the third last line appeared squared. So assuming the form of F, only the E's should get a minus sign, which is also in your desired result. Moreover, your factoring out of c is wrong, you should get an overall factor of $\frac{1}{c^2}$. This is either in the factored-out form or in the factored form the right result,i.e. $F_{\mu\nu}F_{\mu\nu}=2(B^2-\frac{E^2}{c^2})$, not your the stated one .

Comment: Thanks for your answer! You are absolutely right (I have eddited the calculations accordingly). This is a calculation left as excercise on some notes i'm studying from, and am only given the result I should arrive to, $c^2B^2 - E^2$. There is still this factor of $2/c^2$ that bugs me, and I cant find a book where the covariant formulation of electrodynamics with imaginary time relativity is made. Is this result still valid, though?

Comment: Are you sure that $c^2 B^2-E^2$ is really the desired result? I mean the units of $F_{\mu \nu}F^{\mu \nu}$ must be the same either in real or imaginary time. However, the result, which is given you is definitely not in the right units...so I would say, that your result of the calculation is right. The result, which is given you, is wrong.